# AngularJS redirect to login if Refresh (JWT) token gets unauthorized (401 response)

Tags: angularjs, jwt, refresh-token, csrf-token

I'm facing issue redirecting user to login page if refresh (jwt) token gets unauthorized (after first token expires). There are 2 scenarios of un-authorization of tokens;

- 1st: When jwt token gets expire based on 401 response, than a new refresh service is called for generating new token via $http-interceptors (config).
- 2nd: When refresh token also gets unauthorized (401) response, this is when a user should redirect to login page.

I'm able to send refresh token on 1st scenario and its working fine as expected, but I'm not able to redirect user to login page if refresh token also get unauthorized (401) response.

Here is my code;

**authInterceptor.service.js**

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('AuthorizationTokenService', AuthorizationTokenService);

AuthorizationTokenService.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', '$cookies'];
function AuthorizationTokenService($q, $injector, $cookies) {
  // Local storage for token
  var tokenVM = {
    accessToken: null
  };

  // Subscribed listeners which will get notified when new Access Token is available
  var subscribers = [];

  // Promise for getting new Access Token from backend
  var deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;

  var service = {
    getLocalAccessToken: getLocalAccessToken,
    refreshAccessToken: refreshAccessToken,
    isAccessTokenExpired: isAccessTokenExpired,
    subscribe: subscribe
  };

  return service;

  ////////////////////////////////////

  // Get the new Access Token from backend
  function refreshAccessToken() {

    // If already waiting for the Promise, return it.
    if( deferedRefreshAccessToken ) {

      return deferedRefreshAccessToken.promise 

    } else {

      deferedRefreshAccessToken = $q.defer();

      // Get $http service with $injector to avoid circular dependency
      var http = $injector.get('$http');

      http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api_url',
        params: {
          grant_type: 'refresh',
          id_token: $cookies.get('access_token')
        }
      })
        .then(function mySucces(response) {
          var data = response.data;
          if( data ){
            // Save new Access Token
            $cookies.put('access_token', data.access_token);

            if( $cookies.get('access_token') ) {

              // Resolve Promise
              deferedRefreshAccessToken.resolve(data.access_token);

              // Notify all subscribers
              notifySubscribersNewAccessToken(data.access_token);
              deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;
            }
          }
        }, function myError(error) {
          deferedRefreshAccessToken.reject(error);
          deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;
        });

      return deferedRefreshAccessToken.promise;
    } 

  }

  function getLocalAccessToken() {
    // get accesstoken from storage - $cookies
    if ( $cookies.get('access_token') ) {
      var access_token = $cookies.get('access_token')
      return access_token;
    }
  }

  function isAccessTokenExpired() {
    // Check if expiresAt is older then current Date
  }

  function saveToken(accessToken) {
    // get accesstoken from storage - $cookies
    var access_token = $cookies.put('access_token');

    console.log('access_token ' + access_token);

    return access_token;
  }

  // This function will call all listeners (callbacks) and notify them that new access token is available
  // This is used to notify the web socket that new access token is available
  function notifySubscribersNewAccessToken(accessToken) {
    angular.forEach(subscribers, function(subscriber) {
      subscriber(accessToken);
    });
  }

  // Subscribe to this service. Be notifyed when access token is renewed
  function subscribe(callback) {
    subscribers.push(callback);
  }
}
```

**And in Config (app.js)**

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  // Push httpRequestInterceptor
  // $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');

  //Intercept all http requests
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', '$q', "AuthorizationTokenService", "$cookies", function ($injector, $q, AuthorizationTokenService, $cookies) {
    var cachedRequest = null;

    return {
      request: function (config) {
        //If request if for API attach Authorization header with Access Token
        if (config.url.indexOf("api") != -1) {
          // var accessToken = AuthorizationTokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
          console.log('cookie ' + $cookies.get('access_token'));
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('access_token');
        }
        return config;
      },
      responseError: function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
          // Detect if reponse error is 401 (Unauthorized)
          case 401:

          // Cache this request
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          if(!cachedRequest) {
            // Cache request for renewing Access Token and wait for Promise
            cachedRequest = AuthorizationTokenService.refreshAccessToken();
          }

          // When Promise is resolved, new Access Token is returend 
          cachedRequest.then(function(accessToken) {
            cachedRequest = null;
            if (accessToken) {
              // Resend this request when Access Token is renewed
              $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(resp) {
                // Resolve this request (successfully this time)
                deferred.resolve(resp);
              },function(resp) {
                deferred.reject();
                console.log('success: refresh token has expired');
              });
            } else {
              // If any error occurs reject the Promise
              console.log('error: refresh token has expired');
              deferred.reject();
            }
          }, function(response) {
            // If any error occurs reject the Promise
            cachedRequest = null;
            deferred.reject();
            return;
          });

          return deferred.promise;
        }

        // If any error occurs reject the Promise
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  }]);
}
```

Both in **service** & **config**, I've tried to implement that redirects user based on dual 401 (mean refresh token also gets expired and respond back with 401).

I also tried with multiple descendant 401 condition but that didn't work as well. (example below)

```
responseError: function (response) {
  // Detect if reponse error is 401 (Unauthorized)
  if (response.status === 401) {

    // Cache this request
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(!cachedRequest) {
      // Cache request for renewing Access Token and wait for Promise
      cachedRequest = AuthorizationTokenService.refreshAccessToken();
    }

    // When Promise is resolved, new Access Token is returend 
    cachedRequest.then(function(accessToken) {
      cachedRequest = null;
      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log('refresh token also expired');
        $location.path('/login');
      } else {
        // Resend this request when Access Token is renewed
        $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(resp) {
          // Resolve this request (successfully this time)
          deferred.resolve(resp);
        },function(resp) {
          deferred.reject();
          console.log('success: refresh token has expired');
        });
      }
    }, function(response) {
      // If any error occurs reject the Promise
      cachedRequest = null;
      deferred.reject();
      return;
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Based on above code, please guide me what I'm doing wrong or maybe there might be something wrong with login/implementation. Either case please do help me. Thanks

Comment: guys anything to add here which help me fix my issue! that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this solved simply with below lines of code;

**Config** (app.js)

```
// Cache this request
var deferred = $q.defer();
if(!cachedRequest) {
    // Cache request for renewing Access Token and wait for Promise
    cachedRequest = AuthorizationTokenService.refreshAccessToken();
} else {
    // this is where it checks for request token expiry
    do_logout();
}
```